# KENDOUI give group header

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

As we can give common group header in normal telerik grid as shown in below example,

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Can we do same for KENDOUI - grid in MVC? i looked into demo but i did not found anything like this.

If its possible can you please provide with example?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly multi-headers are not supported by the Kendo Grid. However you can try to insert some html into the thead of the Grid and make it look like this:

```
$('#grid').data().kendoGrid.thead.prepend("<tr><td colspan=2>foo</td><td colspan=3>bar</td></tr>")
```

Check the following example I created:

http://jsbin.com/edamuj/605/edit

I hope this helps.

***EDIT***

***As from Q3 2014 MultiHeaders are supported and a demo is available [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders).***